# Installing python-pyxattr on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

While installing some python packages I am getting an error saying:

```
root@baal-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/Stitch/build/reqs# pip install -r lnx_requirements.txt
The directory '/home/baal/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/baal/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: colorama==0.3.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: email==4.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied: logging==0.4.9.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect==4.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: pycrypto==2.6.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied: PyInstaller==3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 6))
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil==2.5.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: python-xlib==0.18 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 8))
Requirement already satisfied: pyudev==0.15 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 9))
Collecting pyxattr==0.5.1 (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading pyxattr-0.5.1.tar.gz
Collecting pyreadline==2.1 (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 11))
  Downloading pyreadline-2.1.zip (109kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 754kB/s 
Collecting readline==6.2.4.1 (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 12))
  Downloading readline-6.2.4.1.tar.gz (2.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.3MB 252kB/s 
Collecting requests==2.12.2 (from -r lnx_requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading requests-2.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (575kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 583kB 588kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pexpect==4.2.1->-r lnx_requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from PyInstaller==3.2->-r lnx_requirements.txt (line 6))
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/baal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil==2.5.3->-r lnx_requirements.txt (line 7))
Installing collected packages: pyxattr, pyreadline, readline, requests
  Running setup.py install for pyxattr ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xaAsqW/pyxattr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-AFlKzP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'xattr' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-ZZaKJ6/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -D_XATTR_VERSION="0.5.1" -D_XATTR_AUTHOR="Iustin Pop" -D_XATTR_EMAIL="iusty@k1024.org" -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c xattr.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/xattr.o
    xattr.c:25:24: fatal error: attr/xattr.h: No such file or directory
     #include <attr/xattr.h>
                            ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xaAsqW/pyxattr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-AFlKzP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xaAsqW/pyxattr/
root@baal-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/Stitch/build/reqs#
```

I've tried installing `pyxattr` with:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-pyxattr
```

And I'm still getting the same problem even after it has installed successfully. I purged the installation and tried again, still the same issue. Is there a trick to installing the that I don't know about, how can I successfully install `python-pyxattr` on Ubuntu 17.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install libattr1-dev

```
apt-get install libattr1-dev
```